# Getting MongoId from PHP object returns NULL

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu-13.10

I'm a bit stumped here.

I've upgraded an Ubuntu 13.10 dev machine to `PHP 5.5.3` with the `PECL Mongo driver 1.5.5`.

Previously on 5.3.6 with 1.3.2.

All of my objects store their `MongoId()` on `$class->_id`;

Randomly, I'm getting that class variable now return as `NULL`, such as:

```
$log = new EmailEventLog;
$log->data = $event;
$log->email = $email->_id;
$log->save();

print_r(var_dump($log));        // contains correct ->_id variable

print_r(var_dump($log->_id));   // NULL
```

Nothing happens in between those two printouts, but I cannot access it!

FYI the class `EmailEventLog` extends `M` which has a `public $_id;` set on it. I've tried bringing that up to the natural class and it's not working still.

Thanks

EDIT - weirdly, closing the object and then getting the _id from the clone returns it as expected!

Comment: Could you include the output of the `var_dump($log)`? Also what happens when you `var_dump($log["_id"])` or `var_dump($log["$_id"])`?

Comment: Hi Larry, `var_dump($log["_id"])` and `var_dump($log["$_id"])` don't work because this it's an object. The output from `print_r(var_dump($log));` is:

`object(EmailEventLog)#504 (5) { ["inserted"]=> object(MongoDate)#495 (2) { ["sec"]=> int(1410177452) ["usec"]=> int(510000) } ["client"]=> int(22) ["email"]=> object(MongoId)#491 (1) { ["$id"]=> string(24) "4e4bd34c47afbc813900001a" } ["_id"]=> object(MongoId)#505 (1) { ["$id"]=> string(24) "540d99ac7bbb88d3038b475f" } }`

It's that last element which contains the _id, a valid object, but when I access it with `$log->_id` it returns NULL!

Comment: Sorry. I'm not sure. Maybe this can help. http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php